# Trouble with reading datasets with read_array in proc fcmp

Tags: arrays, sas, fcmp

I'm trying to read dataset that has 4030 observations and 23 variables. I'm doing that in proc fcmp, using read_array (...) statement. 
Most of the variables have character type, but when I'm trying to read the code:

```
proc fcmp;
    array a[&Numobs., &Nvar.] / NOSYMBOLS ;
    rcl = read_array ("input", a);

    res = write_array ('output', a);
quit;
```

I get error for every character variable:

> ERROR: Column "Variable2" in data set "WORK.input" is not numeric in
>   function READ_ARRAY.

Does read_arrray work only for numeric variables? What am I doing wrong? 
(the rest of my code is simple, and I'm sure it's correct).

I am using SAS Enterprise Guide 4.3.

Answer (score 1):

In SAS all variables in an array must be of the same data type. Your Variable1 is probably numeric, Variable2 is character.

Answer (score 1):

Read_array and write_array are numeric only.  By default you're reading in all columns, but you can specify which columns you're interested in using quoted strings.